# How to disable holidays with weekends and previous days after a certain time from jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I want to create a jQuery datepicker where sunday will be disabled and the previous days will be disabled including the present day after 3.30PM, and holidays also. Here is what I have done as far. can anyone help me how I can add the holidays?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>


        var currentTime = new Date();

        if (currentTime.getHours() >=15 && currentTime.getMinutes() >=30) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                        minDate: 1,      
                    beforeShowDay: noSunday
                  });

                  function noSunday(date){
                      var day = date.getDay();
                                  return [(day > 0), ''];
                  }; 
            });
        } else {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                        minDate: 0,      
                    beforeShowDay: noSunday
                  });

                  function noSunday(date){
                      var day = date.getDay();
                                  return [(day > 0), ''];
                  }; 
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="datepicker" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Sunday disable and the before days are disabled I just need help to disable holiday

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var timeCond = currentTime.getHours() >=15 && currentTime.getMinutes() >=30;
var holidays = ["1/12/2016"]; // add holidays
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: timeCond?1:0,                      
        beforeShowDay: visibilityHandler
      });
      function visibilityHandler(date){
          if(holidays.indexOf(date.toLocaleDateString()) != -1)
             return [false,'']
          return noSunday(date);
      }

      function noSunday(date){
          var day = date.getDay();
                      return [(day > 0), ''];
      }; 

  });
```

Comment: Hi, Sachin thanks for the codes. but can you have a look again and see if anything is missing. when I click on the text input in the browser the calendar is not appearing. But if I make the line beforeShowDay: visibilityHandler; a comment by using // than it appears but the sunday and the holiday is not working when I do this.

Comment: updated. it was a semicolon after visibility handler, removed it

Comment: Still same problem :/

Comment: sorry had some more typos... updated please try again

Comment: Thanks it working now but a little more modification is needed when I select a date its disabling the next date like if I want to disable 2016-01-12 its disabling 2016-01-13

Comment: done. mind the changed date format and `toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to chat. anyway its perfect now thanks a ton :)